# change mobile menu default state from closed to expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I want the mobile menu to have its submenu expanded by default. Now it expands on click.

This function controls the mobile menu. I tried changing **false** with **true** and viceversa, but it didn't work:

```
function(t, e) {
    "use strict";
    Flatsome.behavior("toggle", {
        attach: function(t) {
            jQuery(".widget ul.children, .nav ul.children, .menu .sub-menu", t).each(function() {
                jQuery(this).parent().addClass("has-child").attr("aria-expanded", "false"), jQuery(this).before('<button class="toggle"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></button>')
            }), jQuery(".current-cat-parent", t).addClass("active").attr("aria-expanded", "true").removeClass("current-cat-parent"), jQuery(".toggle", t).click(function(t) {
                var e = jQuery(this);
                e.parent().toggleClass("active"), e.parent().attr("aria-expanded", "false" === e.parent().attr("aria-expanded") ? "true" : "false"), t.preventDefault()
            })
        }
    })
}
```

The HTML code is this:

```
<li id="menu-item-1073" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1073 has-child active" aria-expanded="false">
```

I want the default state for the **aria-expended** to be **true** and make it **false** on click, exactly the other way around from how it is now.

Comment: Well this definitely looks like a `wordpress` menu list element, however, this is a very peculiar implementation. This function is supposed to toggle classes on the html. You should investigate the differences in `classes` in your inspector after you toggle the menu open and just copy/paste/remove those classes in your HTML.

Comment: thanks A LOT, man! your input helped me find the right answer!